# How to fix marker in center of leaflet map after user will drag the map?

Tags: leaflet

I am using a custom map on my node add form. My marker is set to my current location using lat and log. Now I want, whenever a user will drag or move map, marker should be in center (fixed). I tried lot of things like:

```js
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position) {
    $scope.latlong = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    $rootScope.lati= position.coords.latitude ;
    $rootScope.long = position.coords.longitude;

    $scope.map.center = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
        zoom: 20
    };

    $scope.map.markers.now = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
        message: "Usted esta aqui!",
        draggable: false,
        focus: true
    };

    if ($rootScope.locationresults == undefined) {
        Util.getAddressOf(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude).then(function(location) {
            $rootScope.locationresults = location[0].formatted_address;
            console.log(location);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    $scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMap.move", function(event, args) {
        $scope.map.markers.now.setLatLng([0,0]).update();
        //$scope.map.markers.now.lat = $scope.map.center.lat;
        //$scope.map.markers.now.lng = $scope.map.center.lng;
        console.info(JSON.stringify($scope.map.markers.now));
    });

    $scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMap.drag", function(event, args){
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.map.center));
        //$scope.map.markers.now.setLatLng(0,0);
        $scope.map.markers.now.lat = $scope.map.center.lat;
        $scope.map.markers.now.lng = $scope.map.center.lng;

    });

    $scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend", function(event, args) {
        console.log("moviendo");
        $rootScope.lati= args.model.lat ;
        $rootScope.long = args.model.lng;
        Util.getAddressOf(args.model.lat, args.model.lng).then(function(location) {
            $rootScope.locationresults = location[0].formatted_address;
            $scope.latlong = args.model.lat + "," + args.model.lng;
            console.log(location);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: You might be interested in [Leaflet.MapCenterCoord](https://github.com/xguaita/Leaflet.MapCenterCoord) plugin, [Leaflet.FeatureSelect](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.FeatureSelect) plugin, or also look at other [selection plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#areaoverlay-selection).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could place a fake marker, placing a div with background image on top of the map and placing it with absolute position and pointing always to the center of the map.

Example:

```css
.map-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.map-marker-centered{
  background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/marker--v1.png') no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
  <div class="map-marker-centered"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Fake marker centered on map]

Comment: Thanks .. !!  I do it

Comment: I followed exactly your code into the snippet and it's not working, can you kindly check it?

Comment: I restored as it was before when you left it, because I was making too many changes which you might not like. I will post an answer myself, considering your suggestions

Comment: Good! Is not make any sense changing too much an answer. The code is only a sample to show the way

Answer (score 2):

You can place a "fake" marker composed from a background image placed always at the center of the map. You can also detect when map moves and get the coordinates to where the marker points to. Run the snippet:

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)

// add the OpenStreetMap tiles
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  { subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'] })
  .addTo(mymap)
  
mymap.on("moveend", function () {
  console.log(mymap.getCenter().toString());
});
```

```css
.map { 
  height: 280px; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.map-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.map-marker-centered {
  background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/marker--v1.png");
  width: 50px;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script> 
 
<div class="map-container">
  <div class="map-marker-centered"></div>
  <div id="mapid" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! however the latitude is slightly incorrect

Comment: @PaoloBenvenuto if it works, please upvote it :) you need only some adjustments to correct the values