# Finding center of Leaflet.js map after mouse move

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to detect after user move where the center of the map is. Currently I have this piece of code responsible for detecting what is the latitude and longitude of beginning of the mouse move:

```
var lat, lng;

    mymap.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
       lat = ev.latlng.lat;
       lng = ev.latlng.lng;
    });

    document.getElementById("mapid").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log(lat + ' - ' + lng);

        return false;
    });
```

Unfortunately it is not working as I'd imagine. I tried to find some event responsible for stopping of moving and beside drag end event which is only for markers, not just move I couldn't find such. Also the second problem would be then - how to detect the center of map.

Does anyone has any solution for this?

Comment: The answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68362453/1243247

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to keep track of the center of the map, you should be using `mymap.getCenter()` instead of `ev.latlng`.